# how do you get a windows 8 store app to display only a numeric keypad

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, numeric-keypad

how do you get a windows 8 store app to display only a numeric keypad?
I want the user to see only a numeric keypad when they click into a TextBox

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the input scope on the element e.g.

```
      <TextBox x:Name="txtBox" InputScope="Number" />
```

Keep in mind this will only get the number keyboard. The user could still manually change to the alphanumeric keyboard and input text. You will still need to validate the entry.